# Referencing an Active-x control with variable in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a variable for Check boxes in my worksheet so that I can refence a larger number of those in loop.

It looks like this:
[The worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heLkn.png)

The purpose is to make the schedule (Blue background) able to highlight the names you select with the checkboxes (On the left in the green list).

To do this I would like the loop to go through all of those checkboxes and see if they're true for the corresponding name on the same row. I've gotten this far:

```
Sub Test_ReplaceWithArray()

'State var
Dim Names(54) As String
Dim ChkBx As String
Dim Personal As Range
Dim n, m, i, j, ChkNr, numOfEmployees, numOfWeeks As Integer


    'Set var
    Set Personal = Range("A3:A55")
    numOfEmployees = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Personal)
    numOfWeeks = Worksheets("Schemaläggning").numOfWeeksBox.Value
    n = 1
    m = 3
    i = 3
    j = 3
    ChkNr = 1
    ChkBx = ("CheckBox" & ChkNr)

'Fill array
    Do Until n > numOfEmployees
        Cells(i, 1).Select
            If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False _
            And ChkBx = True Then
            Names(n) = ActiveCell.Value
            i = i + 1
            n = n + 1
            ChkNr = ChkNr + 1
        ElseIf IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True Then
            i = i + 1
            n = n + 1
            ChkNr = ChkNr + 1
        End If
Loop

'Make Bold or Grey if in array
    Do Until m > numOfWeeks + 2
        Cells(m, j).Select
            If j <= 7 And IsInArray(ActiveCell.Value, Names) = True Then
                    Selection.Font.Bold = True
                    j = j + 1
            ElseIf j <= 7 And IsInArray(ActiveCell.Value, Names) = False Then
                    With Selection.Font
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                        .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
                    End With
                    j = j + 1
            ElseIf j = 8 Then
                    j = 3
                    m = m + 1
            End If
Loop

End Sub
```

The point is to have the name on the row (In the green list) put into an array and then look at each name in the schedule. If the name in the cell of the schedule is contained within the array the name will be boldened but if it is'nt it will be turned grey. I have allready made a comparison function to see if the names are contained in the array that works (tested it before continuing with the checkbox references).

But I get runtime error 13 at:

```
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False _
        And ChkBx = True Then
```

I definatly suspect that I don't know how to reference the control properly but I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cCont As Control

For Each cCont In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" Then
        cCont.Value = False
    End If
Next cCont
```

This is a sample of what I use to loop through all controls in a userform. Hopefully you can adjust it to your needs.

for worksheets objects:

```
Sub LoopListBoxes() 
Dim OleObj As OLEObject 

For Each OleObj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects 
    If OleObj.progID = "Forms.ListBox.1" Then 
        MsgBox OleObj.Object.ListCount 
    End If 
Next OleObj 
End Sub 

CheckBox = Forms.CheckBox.1 
ComboBox = Forms.ComboBox.1 
CommandButton = Forms.CommandButton.1 
Frame = Forms.Frame.1 
Image = Forms.Image.1 
Label = Forms.Label.1 
ListBox = Forms.ListBox.1 
MultiPage = Forms.MultiPage.1 
OptionButton = Forms.OptionButton.1 
ScrollBar = Forms.ScrollBar.1 
SpinButton = Forms.SpinButton.1 
TabStrip = Forms.TabStrip.1 
TextBox = Forms.TextBox.1 
ToggleButton = Forms.ToggleButton.1
```

borrowed from:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=61068

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I think what I need is just a way to reference a checkbox from within a module. One problem is that if I am going to loop through all of the controls I have to loop through a lot of controls I don't need. And I need to reference the control from an excel worksheet so it doesn't work with a userform reference I'm afraid. So this did'nt really work for me unless I'm missing something. 

Could you maybe do something like this?


    Dim ChkBx As MSForms.CheckBox
       Worksheets("Schemaläggning").ChkBx(n).Value = True